# Как получить доступ к state другого компонента

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

Хочу получить доступ к state компонента Nav
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код нжуно прикладывать в текстовом виде.

Comment: В общем случае никак. А зачем? Какую задачу вы хотите этим решить?

Comment: например даже для того чтобы использовать библиотеку toastify. и добавить ее только в App.js , и уже к нему обращаться из других компонентов, чтобы уведомления отображались на всех страницах